# Rotating the background image of a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `FrameLayout.` I set a background of it. now I want to rotate it programmatically when rotation changed in `onConfigurationChanged`.

I did this but it's changing all layout rotation

```
frameLayout.setRotation(180)
```

I don't want to put different rotation images.
 how to only change the rotation of just background image, not whole layout?

Comment: 1. Rotate the bitmap and set. 2. Use ImageView as placeholder for background and rotate it.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I have vector image not png

Comment: Vector Image, I assume, is in your drawable folder?

Answer (score 0):

This code for only rotate an image :

> ```
>         android:rotation="90"
> ```

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_divider"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@android:drawable/image" />
```